# NSURLSession and image cache

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, swift2, nsurlcache

In my iOS 9+ Swift 2.2 application, I'm downloading multiple images with NSURLSession's dataWithRequest method :

```
    let session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: self.configuration)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: self.url)
    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in
        // Handle image
    }

    dataTask.resume()
    session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
```

The question is : How can I limit the image cache size? I can see that my application is using more and more disk space on my device. Is there any way to keep the image cache but to limit the size that my application can use? Is there an expiration by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSURLSession uses shared [NSURLCache](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlcache) to cache responses. If you want to limit disk/memory usage of a shared cache you should [create](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlcache/1415637-init) a new cache and set it as a default one:

```
let URLCache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: 4 * 1024 * 1024, diskCapacity: 20 * 1024 * 1024, diskPath: nil)
NSURLCache.setSharedURLCache(URLCache)
```

You could find a little more about caching [here](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/).

Comment: When setting a cache limit, what happens when the limit is reached? The old cache get replaced with the new one?

Comment: URLCache keeps information about cached responses: when a response was created, when it was used last time, etc. So if there is no space to save a new response URLCache removes the saved one that was not used for a long time.

Comment: I'm currently not settings any disk capacity and it seems like the default values are not used (20MB of disk capacity), I don't save anything locally and my application is using 60MB of Documents & Data...

Comment: The files are in the fsCachedData folder (I can see many images having names like "0AA8179E-2EA8-449C-8E7F-96B12AC5D2DE"). Any idea why it's using more than the 20MB default value?

Comment: Where do you setup your cache? Are you sure you do it before any requests? What does `currentDiskUsage` property of cache returns?